# Using a PHP variable passed via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I have been searching around for an answer but none are really what I need.

Everything is working fine, the variable is being passed to my PHP file via AJAX, but now I need to know how to actually use it (for the WHERE field of a mysql query).

First, the user clicks something and it calls this AJAX:

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'post', 
url: 'includes/hash.php', 
data: { 
    d: $(s).attr('id') 
},
success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

Then `hash.php` defines the PHP variable from the AJAX post:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['d'])){ 
    $hash = $_POST['d']; 
} ?>
```

And I want it to be displayed in the following HTML in home.php:

```
<section id="pa"> 
    <article> 
        <h1 class="pa">PAINTINGS</h1> 
        <?php echo $hash; ?> 
    </article> 
</section>
```

Updated: Sorry for being unclear, I added the relevant HTML. The user clicks a link, and I eventually want to generate the `WHERE` field of a query based on the ID of the link they click. So I'm using AJAX to pass the variable (the ID) to the PHP file `hash.php`. Right now, it's not working in the MySQL query, so I am just trying to echo the variable for debugging purposes, but I get an error from PHP that it's undefined. I don't know how to use the variable outside of `hash.php` once it's defined via AJAX. Can I only use the variable in `hash.php`, or can I access it somehow in another file? I tried to include `hash.php` into the HTML, but it's still undefined despite the console log telling me that it IS being passed there.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question / problem. Everything looks fine in your code; given a valid POST request with `d` parameter (as you are doing correctly via JavaScript), your `includes/hash.php` script should be able to use `$_POST['d']`

Comment: is hash.php returning any value? echo $hash in hash.php and you should be able to see a string representation on the success: function (data){console.log(data)}

Comment: look in the network tab of your browser console for the parameters of your post request

Comment: I have updated the post. hash.php DOES return a value, but I want to use it in a separate file. How do I access the variable outside of hash.php? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I bet its your $(s) thats causing the problem.

Make sure that you refer to $(s) correctly better yet if you post your html code so we all can see what $(s) refers to.

Comment: $(s) refers to one of the arguments of a function. It is working correctly, though.

Comment: please paste your html code here, we can help you:)